# C++ Qt Creator version recommended for Qt libraries 4.8.5

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've downloaded the Qt libraries 4.8.5 and compiled them with MinGW GCC 4.8.2 and now I would like to use Qt Creator to design the interface of my applications in an interactive way. What version of Qt Creator version is recommended for use with Qt libraries version 4.8.5 and where I can get that specific version. Or can I go with the latest version Qt Creator 3.0.1 for Qt libraries 5.2.1? I'm thinking that the latest version of Qt Creator might use features that are not supported by the 4.8.5 version of Qt libraries.

Comment: Are you going to develop open source app or an closed source app.

Comment: It's going to be an open source app :) (just a hobby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Qt Designer tab of Qt Creator to create "forms" (.ui files) then that part of Qt has been stable for quite some time, and was not changed significantly as far as I know in Qt 5.x so you should be fine with the latest version of Qt Creator.

The QML language has undergone significant changes from 4.x to 5.x and there might be issues using the latest Qt Creator's designer tab to visually edit "Qt Quick" (QML files).  Certainly the very latest version of Qt Creator features much more extensive QML support, including QML debugging.

If this talk of QML versus UI files is a mystery, then you'll need to read up on the two technologies and make a decision which to use;  but essentially if you're set on 4.8.x that probably means using the older UI files.  I use these myself and they're fine for traditional desktop applications.

Qt Quick 2 in 5.x is very nice, and enables animated, modern, styled user-interfaces with a powerful scripting language and bindings through to C++, however there is more to master going down that route, and it would mean using Qt 5.x.

Comment: I would go with Qt 5 but that library is huge and applications that use it eat allot of memory at runtime and all I need is the QtCore, QtGui and QtOpenGL (compiled with bare minimal features) basically just a simple GUI library for my app that supports an OpenGL canvas. Anyway I think I'll download the Qt libraries 4.8.5 in binary form and see what version of Qt Creator it uses and then download that version manually and compile it. If no one provides another answer today I'll mark your answer as solved. Thank you :)

Comment: I've been able to use the Qt Creator 3.0.1 with Qt Libraries 4.8.5 without any problems so far. Although I haven't experimented with all the widgets and stuff I'd say your answer is somewhat valid.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Qt 5.2.1. You are certainly wrong here

> I would go with Qt 5 but that library is huge and applications that
>   use it eat allot of memory at runtime

Instead in Qt5 it is more modularised and better and has more classes. If you compile Qt 4.8.5 for static compilation, and same with Qt 5.2 (with opengl enabled and icu & webkit disabled during compilation) the difference in size of binaries created is less than 1MB, the total size of skeleton app is around 6MB.

It is same in case of dynamic linking where the difference in memory consumption of both is almost same (around 15MB) for skeleton app.